# Calculating Average and Maximum from a .txt file

Tags: c++

I have a text file that looks like this (but many more lines):

```
9527,88147
4963,75407
448P,34361
2545,29046
9095,258T8
```

How would I find the average of all the numbers in the 1st column? I know how to find the average but I can't seem to get it to work due to the `P` in one of the numbers in the 1st column. So I how would I find the average while ignoring the `chars`?

Also, how would I find the Max number in just the 2nd column while ignoring the char `T`?

Here is my code for calculating the average:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream file;
  string fileName;
  cout << "Please input the filename: ";
  cin >> fileName;
  file.open(fileName.c_str());
  while(file.fail())
  {
    file.clear();
    cout << "Incorrect filename, please input the filename: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    file.open(fileName.c_str());
  }

  // Calculate the average value of all numbers in the first column and the
  // largest value of all numbers in the second column 
  string line;
  long sum = 0;
  long i = 0;
  long max = 0;
  while (getline(file,line)) 
  {
    string str1, str2;

    size_t idx = line.find(",");
    str1 = line.substr(0,idx);
    str2 = line.substr(idx+1);

    str1.erase(std::remove_if(str1.begin (), str1.end (), ::isalpha), str1.end ());
    str2.erase(std::remove_if(str2.begin (), str2.end (), ::isalpha), str2.end ());

    int n;
    sum += stoi(str1); 
      n  = stoi(str2); 

    if(i == 0)
      max = n;
    else
    {
      if ( n > max )
        max = n;
    }

    ++i;
  }

  // The total number of rows in the file
  int rows = 0;
  {
    ++rows;
  }

  // Find the invalid numbers with letters in them and output them






  file.close();

  // Output of calculations
  cout.precision(4);
  cout << "The average value of all numbers in the first column: " << fixed << static_cast<double>(sum)/i << endl;
  cout << "The largest value of all numbers in the second column: " << max << endl;
  cout << "The total number of rows in the file is: " << i << endl;
  //cout << "The invalid numbers are: " << letters << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My output for the average just says `nan`.

Comment: Are you reading those numbers in that text file into `number`?

Comment: Also, nNumbers is 0.  That might be why you're getting `nan`

Comment: @MattGregory I'm not sure

Comment: @MattGregory So I don't need to add an exception for the char?

Comment: Okay, you're opening the file, that part's good.  Then you're declaring some variables, which allocates memory.  That's also good.  Now you need to read those numbers from the file and store them in the array.  (You actually don't need to store them in an array, you could just total them and count them as you read them in).  But anyway the next thing you need to do is read them in from the file.

Comment: Why are you trying to compute the average of numbers you haven't read from the file yet?

Comment: @MattGregory How do I read the from the file? like this: int i;
  int numberTotal = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < nNumbers; i++)
  {
    int nNumbers;
    file >> nNumbers;
    file.ignore(1000, 10);
    numberTotal += number[i];
  }

Comment: Look at this line in your code: `cin >> fileName;`  That's how you do it, but you're going to be using `file` instead of `cin`, and you're going to be reading into an `int` rather than a `string`.  But you have to be careful because once you read the int, the rest of the characters on that line are still going to be in the input buffer waiting to be read.  You can read the data from that point to the end of line by reading a `string`.  I don't know what you want to do with that data, but it looks like you want to throw it away, so if that's the case then read it in and move on.  Cheers!

Comment: You can't use a for loop without knowing how many times you want to loop.

Comment: @MattGregory _"You can't use a for loop without knowing how many times you want to loop."_ That's not even approximately true.

Comment: This loop `while(getline(file, row))` is meaningless. Try moving `++rows;` to the first loop and delete the second loop.

Comment: NO NO NO. REMOVE `while(getline(file, row))`. Use One LOOP. By the way, the variable i is the number of rows. No need to add another variable for counting rows.

Comment: @CroCo I was just trying to get her to think about what she's doing.  You just did her homework for her.  Good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for removing chars, you can use `erase()` and `isalpha` for this matter. See the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip> // std::setprecision
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream file("data.txt");
    string line;
    long sum = 0;
    long i = 0;
    long max = 0;
    while ( getline(file, line) ) {

        string str1, str2;

        size_t idx = line.find(",");
        str1 = line.substr(0,idx);
        str2 = line.substr(idx+1);

        str1.erase(std::remove_if(str1.begin (), str1.end (), isalpha), str1.end ());
        str2.erase(std::remove_if(str2.begin (), str2.end (), isalpha), str2.end ());

        int n;
        sum += stoi(str1); 
           n  = stoi(str2); 

        if( i == 0 )
            max = n;
        else{
            if ( n > max )
                max = n;
        }

        ++i;
    }

    cout.precision(4);
    cout << "average column 1: " << fixed << static_cast<double>(sum)/i << " and max column 2: " << max << endl;
}
```

The txt file is

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
4P,4
5,5T
```

and the output is

```
average column 1: 3.0000 and max column 2: 5
```

Comment: @GingerbreadLemonade Check [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) which header you missed to include.

Comment: @GingerbreadLemonade, which compiler you are using? Also, you are not following my code exactly. You need to cast `sum/i`.

Comment: @user0042 I have that header included

Comment: @GingerbreadLemonade, your code is working fine in my machine.

Comment: @CroCo Just wondering, where you go if (i == 0) max = n;, could you get rid of that by starting max at std::numeric_limits<long>::lowest(), and then just comparing n against max, without having the if (i==0)?

Comment: @user0042 I'm using namespace std;

Comment: @GingerbreadLemonade _"I'm using namespace std;"_ You are aware you shouldn't do that? Almost certainly you did something wrong with the parameters you pass to `std::remove_if() in that case.`

Comment: replace `isalpha` with `::isalpha`.

Comment: @CroCo I'm using Terminal for MacOS

Comment: REMOVE this `while(getline(file, row))`. or you need to close the file and reopen it for the second loop.

Comment: @GingerbreadLemonade: `i` is equal to number of rows read from file (as it is used in average calculation to divide the sum of first column numbers, so it must be count of rows)

Comment: @GingerbreadLemonade, accept the answer if it solves your problem by clicking on the check mark beside the question.